# How to remove a series from DynamicTimeSeriesCollection?

Tags: jfreechart

Anyone can guide me on how to remove a series from `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`?

In this example, I want to delete series `S1`

```
DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(50, 120, new Second());
dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "S1");
dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 1, "S2");
```

I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks GrahamA for your answer.
Cause i need to touch seriesCount is private, so i must create a new class named DynamicTimeSeriesCollectionModified (copy-paste from DynamicTimeSeriesCollection) and write my own removeSeries and it works.

```
public void deleteSeries(int seriesNumber) {

        //remove item in valueHistory array
        List<ValueSequence> listValueHistory = new ArrayList<ValueSequence>(Arrays.asList(valueHistory));
        listValueHistory.remove(seriesNumber);
        valueHistory = listValueHistory.toArray(valueHistory);

        //remove item in seriesKeys array
        List<Comparable> listSeriesKeys = new ArrayList<Comparable>(Arrays.asList(seriesKeys));
        listSeriesKeys.remove(seriesNumber);
        seriesKeys = listSeriesKeys.toArray(seriesKeys);                

        //update seriesCount
        seriesCount--;
        fireSeriesChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` stores values in an array of `ValueSequence`.  By default a `ValueSequence` can't be deleted but as `ValueSequence` is protected you can subclass `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` wrtie your own `removeSeries` method and see if that solves your problem.

Take a look at `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection#addSeries` and reverse the steps, remember to call `fireSeriesChanged()` at the end.

Comment: Cause i need to touch seriesCount is private, so i must create a new class named DynamicTimeSeriesCollectionModified (copy-paste from DynamicTimeSeriesCollection) and write my own removeSeries and it works. Thanks GrahamA.